# Printing good characters into bad characters unknown characters

Tags: java, windows, pdf, printing, pdfbox

PDF files contain some French accent characters such as: e with some tick markt on top of them same with u or so.

[image]

When i check the PDF files before printing, i can see they are absolutely correct, i can read them in that PDF, i can zoom in and copy them perfectly fine.

But the moment Java touch it and prints it. Everything just does not work as it suppose to be.

How can i fix it please? the cloud version of that PDF is perfect but once my following code use to handle the file, then all those characters become broken in the print copy.

```
import java.awt.print.PrinterException;
import java.awt.print.PrinterJob;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import javax.print.DocPrintJob;
import javax.print.PrintService;
import javax.print.attribute.HashPrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.PrintRequestAttributeSet;
import javax.print.attribute.standard.MediaTray;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.printing.PDFPageable;

public class PrintA4 {

  public static boolean saveFile(URL url, String file) throws IOException {
    boolean download_status = false;

    System.out.println("open");
    InputStream in = url.openStream();
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(new File(file));
    System.out.println("reading file...");
    int length = -1;
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > -1) {
        fos.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    fos.close();
    in.close();

    download_status = true;
    System.out.println("downloaded");
    return download_status;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, PrinterException {  

    String downloaded_filename = "C:/pdf.pdf";
    String download_pdf_from = "http://www.example.com/1.pdf" ;
    String downloaded_filename_open_as_pdf = "C:\\pdf.pdf";
    String printerNameDesired = "Brother HL-6180DW series";

    PrintService[] services = PrinterJob.lookupPrintServices();
    DocPrintJob docPrintJob = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
      System.out.println(services[i]);
    }   

    try{
      URL url = new URL(download_pdf_from);

      if(saveFile(url, downloaded_filename)) {
        try {
          PDDocument pdf = PDDocument.load(new File(downloaded_filename_open_as_pdf));
          PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
          for (int i = 0; i < services.length; i++) {
           if (services[i].getName().equalsIgnoreCase(printerNameDesired)) {
             docPrintJob = services[i].createPrintJob();
           }
          }

          job.setPrintService(docPrintJob.getPrintService());
          job.setPageable(new PDFPageable(pdf));


          PrintRequestAttributeSet pset = new HashPrintRequestAttributeSet();          
          pset.add(MediaTray.BOTTOM); 
          job.print(pset);

        } catch (Exception e) {
          System.out.println("[FAIL]");
        }      
      } else {
        System.out.println("[FAIL]");
      }      
    } catch (Exception ae) {
      System.out.println("[FAIL]");
    }


  }
}
```

Comment: What PDFBox version are you using? Hopefully 2.0.2.

Comment: Can you share a sample PDF to reproduce the issue with?

Comment: (Not related to your problem) `PDDocument.load(url.openStream())` would save a lot of code.

Comment: I am using PDFBox 2.0.2

Comment: @mkl: here you can find a sample PDF: https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/cd0801474ad2927f93d64820a1a48cd820160808145756/75c3a697f17091a47195a9a4076c250720160808145756/646ac2

Comment: I'm able to print it and the accents appear properly. Could there be a problem with your classpath, that you have some old versions there? To be sure, use the command line app, and do this: `java -jar pdfbox-app-2.0.2.jar PrintPDF Untitleddocument.pdf`. Other idea: save the file that you download programmatically and look whether it is still the same file. (Does your server bring the correct MIME type?)

Comment: Furthermore, inspecting the file does not reveal anything special about those characters, so there is no plausible reason why PDFBox should fail to render them.